# Objective-C and calling methods from another class: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I created a method in `ClassA` and want to call it in `ClassB.m`.

In `ClassA.h` I have this:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject <NSCoding>
...
+ (NSInteger) methodA:(CGPoint)touchPoint;
...
@end
```

And in `ClassA.m` I have declared `methodA`:

```
+ (NSInteger)methodA:(CGPoint)touchPoint
{
// return an integer based on touchPoint's value
}
```

And in `ClassB.m`:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
...
-(void)methodThatCallsMethodA
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSInteger integerUsingClassA = [ClassA methodA:touchPoint];
    // do some stuff
}
```

I have a feeling that the issue lies in how I am calling the method and that the object, which is right now `ClassA`, is wrong, but I'm not sure. The error is `unrecognized selector sent to class ...`. Keep in mind that if I create a method identical to `methodA` within `ClassB.m` I am able to call it like I am calling in `methodThatCallsMethodA` on the object `self` with no problem.

~~~~~~~~~~~

I have also tried this in `ClassB.h`:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@interface...
@property(nonatomic, retain)ClassA *objectOfClassA;
...
@end
```

And changed `ClassB.m`:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@synthesize objectOfClassA;
- (void)methodThatCallsMethodA
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    if(!self.objectOfClassA)
         self.objectOfClassA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    NSInteger integerUsingClassA = [self.objectOfClassA methodA:touchPoint];
    NSLog(@"ClassA: %i", integerUsingClassA);
}
```

But now it's warning that `instance method -methodA not found`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you quoted the entire error message exactly.

Comment: I tried your code, putting the calling code in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, and it worked fine.

Comment: **The error** was that Xcode was using older versions of the files. It had crashed earlier in the day and wasn't actually saving/building my changes although it said it was. When I returned today all changes from the previous version were lost. Now the code I posted (first try) above works fine. @HotLicks thank you for the tip; I am new here and not sure how much to include in questions.

Comment: Xcode 4, in particular, is apt to miss changes to files, especially "minor" 1-2 character changes.  I find it best, eg, to insert and then remove a newline when making a one-character change to a `#define` flag, eg.  Otherwise you end up running with the old flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is correct for calling a class method part of `ClassA` in `ClassB` (marked by `+(NSInteger)` in `ClassA`). The second part is correct for calling an instance method part of `ClassA` in `ClassB` (marked by `-(NSInteger)` in `ClassA`).

The error was the fact that Xcode 4 wasn't saving changes and was building using older versions.